# SQLite Database Insert Error Constraint

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-store-apps

I am making a web service call that returns a message bean that has 50 packets. I then put it into my SQLite the following way

```
public void DashboardHandler(Array Bean, long cNum)
    {
        foreach (invoiceSummaryBean ib in Bean)
        {
            var dash = new dashboardCustomer
            {
                actualUsage = ib.actualUsage,
                serviceCost = ib.serviceCost,
                mmbtu = ib.mmbtu,
                OptiServiceCost = ib.optimizedServiceCost,
                period = ib.period,
                periodType = ib.periodType,
                service = ib.service,
                serviceType = ib.serviceType,
                measure = ib.unitOfMeasure,                    
                customerNumber = cNum
            };

            try
            {
                db.insertDashboard(dash);
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

My insert Method

```
public async Task insertDashboard(dashboardCustomer d)
    {
        try
        {
            await db.InsertAsync(d);
        }
        catch(SQLiteException)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

My Table

```
[Table("dashboardCustomer")]
public class dashboardCustomer
{

    public long customerNumber { get; set; }        
    public int period { get; set; }
    public string periodType { get; set; }
    public string service { get; set; }
    public double actualUsage { get; set; }
    public double mmbtu { get; set; }
    public double OptiServiceCost { get; set; }        
    public double serviceCost {get; set;}        
    public string serviceType { get; set; }        
    public string measure { get; set; }


}
```

When it tries to insert it crashes saying {"Constraint"}?

Not sure what the problem is. I need all 50 packets to insert into the table.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but you may need to label the properties in dashboardCustomer as Columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue with this problem. I had to change how the table was created. It strangely has to be recreated every time new data is inserted.

Comment: In many sqlite database systems such as sqlite-net (not the one you are using going off your syntax) you do something like _connection.CreateTable<YOURTYPEHERE>(); This doesn't create a new table, what it does is insures that it exists or creates it if it doesn't exist.